# customer group restriction

Tags: product, configurable-product, controllers

**I want to apply some rule for customer group for example if general user can buy only single quantity of any product and wholesaler can buy limitless product quantity and retail can buy specific quantity and so on for different customer groups. For maximum quantity means particular group cannot buy more than its allowed limit.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step1:
copy `app>code>core>Mage>CatalogInventory>Model>Observer.php` to `app>code>local>Mage>CatalogInventory>Model>Observer.php`

And `goto` function `checkQuoteItemQty(`) add below

```
 $groupId=null; 


$groupId = =$quoteItem->getQuote()->getQuote()->getCustomerGroupId();
    if (!$groupId) {
        $groupId =  Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')
        ->getCustomerGroupId();;
    }
```

**after**

```
if (!$quoteItem || !$quoteItem->getProductId() || !$quoteItem->getQuote()
            || $quoteItem->getQuote()->getIsSuperMode()) {
            return $this;
        }
```

**Then in this function change**

```
$result = $stockItem->checkQuoteItemQty($rowQty, $qtyForCheck, $qty);
```

**to**

```
 $result = $stockItem->checkQuoteItemQty($rowQty, $qtyForCheck, $qty,$groupId);
```

**And from**

```
 $result = $stockItem->checkQuoteItemQty($optionQty, $qtyForCheck, $optionValue);
```

**to**

```
 $result = $stockItem->checkQuoteItemQty($optionQty, $qtyForCheck, $optionValue,$groupId);
```

Step2:

```
`copy app>code>core>Mage>CatalogInventory>Model>Stock>Item.php` to 


   app>code>local>Mage>CatalogInventory>Model>Stock>Item.php
```

edit checkQuoteItemQty function:

edit below code

```
      if ($this->getMaxSaleQty() && $qty > $this->getMaxSaleQty()) {
$result->setHasError(true)
    ->setMessage(
        Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('The maximum quantity allowed for purchase is %s. %s', $this->getMaxSaleQty() * 1,$county_id)
    )
    ->setErrorCode('qty_max')
    ->setQuoteMessage(Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('Some of the products cannot be ordered in requested quantity.'))
    ->setQuoteMessageIndex('qty');
return $result;
 }
```

to

```
if(!is_null($county_id) && $groupid==youmatchgroupid'){
    if ($this->getMaxSaleQty() && $qty > 2) {
    $result->setHasError(true)
        ->setMessage(
            Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('The maximum quantity allowed for purchase is %s. %s', $this->getMaxSaleQty() * 1,$groupid)
        )
        ->setErrorCode('qty_max')
        ->setQuoteMessage(Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('Some of the products cannot be ordered in requested quantity.'))
        ->setQuoteMessageIndex('qty');
    return $result;
     }


}
else{
      if ($this->getMaxSaleQty() && $qty > $this->getMaxSaleQty()) {
    $result->setHasError(true)
        ->setMessage(
            Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('The maximum quantity allowed for purchase is %s. %s', $this->getMaxSaleQty() * 1,$county_id)
        )
        ->setErrorCode('qty_max')
        ->setQuoteMessage(Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('Some of the products cannot be ordered in requested quantity.'))
        ->setQuoteMessageIndex('qty');
    return $result;
     }

}
```

**NOte:**

See code

```
if(!is_null($groupId) && $groupId==$yourgoupid){
```

means yougrouopid ,Just change customer group id

And see condition `if ($this->getMaxSaleQty() && $qty > 2) change 2 to 60 And According to your reference Magento: limit product max quantity to 1 per order. quantity 2 = 2 orders`

**Importnote: this->getProductId() is given product id.**